# Hide/Disable property pane component based on another component's value

Tags: spfx, sharepoint-framework, spfx-custom-property-pane

[image]

On my property pane for a SPFx web part, I've got a Toggle and a Slider component.

How do make it so that when the Toggle is Off, the Slider is hidden/disabled?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make use of a standard boolean check to determine whether your toggle component has value. Based on that, you can show/hide your slider component. You can do this bool check in the `getPropertyPaneConfiguration` method itself as below. Here, if the toggle component is off, we will show an emptly label.

```
protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    let allEventsUrl: any;

    if (this.properties.toggleAllEvents) {
      allEventsUrl = PropertyPaneSlider('maxEvents', {
        label: "Max events",
        min: 1,
        max: 10,
        value: 1,
        showValue: true,
        step: 1
      })
    }
    else {
      allEventsUrl = PropertyPaneLabel('emptyLabel', {
        text: ""
      });
    }
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneToggle('toggleAllEvents', {
                  key: 'toggleAllEvents',
                  label: '',
                  checked: false,
                  onText: "Some text",
                  offText: "Some other text",
                }),
                allEventsUrl
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
```

End result:

**Image 1 - toggle off**

[image]

**Image 2 - toggle on**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering what the standard pattern was for this. I couldn't find any examples.

Comment: This approach is good enough for hiding controls in many cases but it is a bit ugly, as abusing the PropertyPaneLabel control in this way generally leaves unwanted space in the UI often forcing you to re-order controls so that ones that might be hidden appear last in the group.  But that's not always what you want.  I've come up with what I think is a better approach, which I just blogged about here https://kaboodlesoftware.com/2019/10/04/a-rather-useful-empty-spfx-property-pane-control/

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the answer from @GautamSheth but I also thought outputting an empty `PropertyPaneLabel` is definitely not ideal as mentioned by @ColinGardner. However, I also don't think creating a new `PropertyPaneControl` that does nothing is a good idea either.

Here is how I am doing it, which I find to be much simpler and easier to understand for someone else looking at the code.

```
protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    // configure groupFields to show always
    const conditionalGroupFields: IPropertyPaneGroup["groupFields"] = [
      PropertyPaneCheckbox("Field1", {
        text: strings.Field1Label,
      }),
    ];

    // show Field2, only if Field1 is true
    if (this.properties.Field1) {
      conditionalGroupFields.push(
        PropertyPaneCheckbox("Field2", {
          text: strings.Field2Label,
        }),
      );
    }
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          groups: [
            {
              groupFields: conditionalGroupFields,
              groupName: strings.ConditionalGroupFieldsLabel,
            },
          ],
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription,
          },
        },
      ],
    };
  }
```